# Exception while trying to initialise paramiko.SFTPClient on a Dropbear SSH Server with EMPTY Password

Tags: python, ssh, sftp, paramiko

I need to open an SSHClient and an SFTPClient to an SSH Server which is not having a password.

After a lot of googling I found a way to initialize the SSHClient with empty password but I couldn't initialize the SFTPClient.

Below is my code:

```py
from contextlib import suppress
import paramiko

HOST = "127.0.0.1"
USER = "root"
PASS = ""


ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

# HACK to connect to an SSH Server with an EMPTY Password
with suppress(paramiko.AuthenticationException):
    ssh.connect(HOST, username=USER, password=PASS)
ssh.get_transport().auth_none(USER)

# The following line causes the Exception
sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
```

N.b., I don't want to use public keys! I want the solution to work with an empty password also!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue is NOT with the EMPTY password at all.

The server I am connecting to is using `dropbear` for SSH Server and it doesn't support SFTP: [Paramiko Open SFTP to Dropbear SSH Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48408044/paramikos-open-sftp-to-dropbear-ssh-server-raising-eof-during-negotiation-e)

Below is the working implementation:

```py
from contextlib import suppress

import paramiko
import scp

HOST = "127.0.0.1"
USER = "root"
PASS = ""


ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

# HACK to connect to an SSH Server with an EMPTY Password
with suppress(paramiko.AuthenticationException):
    ssh.connect(HOST, username=USER, password=PASS)
ssh.get_transport().auth_none(USER)

try:
    ftp = ssh.open_sftp()
except paramiko.SSHException:
    ftp = scp.SCPClient(ssh.get_transport())
```